# Text-overflow issue with CSS Table for Multi-line checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Yesterday I was having issues with vertical alignment on this multi-line checkbox.  Once that was working I attempted to make it somewhat responsive by having it fill the container its placed in and apply text-overflow elipses to the 3 text labels.  This did not work.

HTML (inline css will be moved to scss once display issues are worked out)

```
<label style="margin-bottom:25px; display:table; table-layout:fixed;" title="checkbox">
  <div style="display:table-cell; width:34px">
    <span class="fancy-checkbox-multiline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="box">
    <span class="box">
        <span class="checker">
            <span class="mark"></span>
    </span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:top; width:100%">
    <div style="display:table; table-layout:fixed;">
      <div style="display:table-cell; font-size:12px; line-height:12px; max-width:100%; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow:hidden;">
        This is the Primary label
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table; table-layout:fixed;">
      <div style="display:table-cell; font-size:10px; line-height:12px; max-width:50%; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow:hidden;">
        This is the 2nd label
      </div>
      <div style="display:table-cell; font-size:10px; line-height:12px; padding-left:10px; max-width:50%; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow:hidden;">
        This is the 3rd label
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; padding-left:20px; line-height:24px;">55
  </div>
</label>
```

At this point my main question has become: Is there a better way to get format this checkbox then using a css table?

Here is a new JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/PolishVendetta/3s7kxta4/13/

Comment: Are you looking for this output? https://jsfiddle.net/3s7kxta4/14/

Comment: Thats a start.  Ideally overflow would only kick in when the labels are too big to be displayed in the area it has.  On my screen when its very wide you still see the ellipsis.